# How to create nest vuejs project

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Is there any way to create nest project?
For example project had two part: user part and admin part. Each part, I created by using vuejs-cli. Now I want to move admin part inside user part so if I run project:

I can access both part of project.
From user part, if I login to admin, I can move to admin part
From admin part, I can move to user part like normal user

Comment: What is the point of having both part separated. You can use vue-router to handle this kink of situation ?

Comment: What is the point of having both apps in the same app if their functionalities differ?

Comment: @mathk Both part have different template library. If using router, it will change the content, but not the layout

Comment: @Borjante they all belong to one website (normal user part and admin part) so I want to put them in the same project. If your are admin, you can go to admin page and using website just like nomal user.

Comment: I said this because I'm working on the same kind of situation like you. I started using the same project for both apps but after some time, I figured that the most optimal way was to split it into 2 projects. Now I have client.example.com and admin.example.com

The main benefit is that the bundle size of each app was cut nearly in half, those making load times faster.

Comment: My project is person so I want to minimize cost: domain, server,... Loading time or project's size are not important.